# How do I dispose class object from List<object>

Tags: c#, .net, object, garbage-collection, dispose

I have a Listbox which have 3 items in which only 1 item can be selected at a time. The properties of these items are accessed from different classes - Alto,Zen,Esteem. I need to use only 1 class at a time.
I am storing these classes in a list array. How can I Dispose my desired classes(according to my logic)?

List of class array

```
List<object> lst = new List<object>();
```

Add each class object to list

```
Alto objAlto = new Alto();
Zen objZen = new Zen();
Esteem objEsteem = new Esteem();

lst.Add(objAlto);
lst.Add(objZen);
lst.Add(objEsteem);
```

My logic to Dispose

[image]

Now my question is, how can I dispose the objects? Why I am not able to get ".Dispose"? Am I missing with any implicit conversion to avail this feature?

Comment: Implement `IDisposable` on your classes and provide a `Dispose` method, Currently you have `List<object>`, You need a `List<YourClass>` with `IDisposable` implemented. One more thing, are you really sure you need `Dispose` ? are you handling any unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to D Stanleys answer, how about so:

```
foreach(var o in lst.OfType<IDisposable>())
{
   o.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Even if o.Dispose() is called, why the actual object is not getting Disposed? Is there any way like using "ref" (just an example) to dispose actual object?

Comment: What do you think `Dispose` is supposed to do? The `Dispose` method  in an `IDisposable` implementation cleans up references to unmanaged resources and references to managed objects that themselves have references to unmanaged resources.

Comment: What do you mean, @SarathAvanavu? It will *eventually* be "disposed", when the GC decides its the best time to do so. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Why I am not able to get ".Dispose"?

Becasue yout list is of tyoe List and `Dispose` is a method of the `IDisposable` interface.  If your list was of type `IDisposable` (or some type that implements `IDisposable`), then you could call `Dispose` directly.

Am I missing with any implicit conversion to avail this feature?

There's not an *implicit* conversion, but if the objects implement `IDisposable` you can explicitly cast them:

```
foreach(object o in lst)
{
   if(o is IDisposable)
      ((IDisposable)o).Dispose();
}
```

However there's a couple of design oddities that I see:

- A list of objects is usually a code smell.  If the objects all implement  a common interface or have a common base class (other then `Object`) it would be better to use a list of a more specific type.
- Typically whatever *creates* an object is responsible for disposing of it.  An alternative is to make whatever contains the objects implement `IDisposable` as well.

Comment: Even if o.Dispose() is called, why the actual object is not getting Disposed? Is there any way like using "ref" (just an example) to dispose actual object?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `.Dispose` does _not_ remove the objects from memory - the Garbage Collector does that, and only when nothing holds a reference to it - so to have the garbage collector clean up the objects you'll need to remove them from the list.